# Merging elements in a CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, whatsapp

I already have a CSS/HTML mockup that makes it look like WhatsApp messaging, but only for conversations between 2 people. I want to add the group-chat feature, which means the names.

It's based on a `<dl>` list, so the HTML looks like this:

```css
.whatsapp {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azdaema/AO3-Skin_Messaging/master/WhatsApp/images/WhatsApp_background.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.whatsapp dt {
  display: none;
}

.whatsapp dd {
  max-width: 65%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.whatsapp dd:after {
  content: attr(time);
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

.whatsapp dd:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.whatsapp dd:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 14px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 9px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}


/*
 * Outgoing texts
 */

.whatsapp .out dd {
  float: right;
  background: #DCF8C6;
}

.whatsapp .out dd:last-child:before {
  border-color: #DCF8C6;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  right: -16px;
}


/*
 * Incoming texts
 */

.whatsapp .in dd {
  float: left;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.whatsapp .in dd:last-child:before {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
  left: -16px;
}


/*
 * Timestamps
 */

.whatsapp .day,
.whatsapp dd sub {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.whatsapp .day {
  width: 100px;
  background: #D4EAF4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.whatsapp dd sub {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}


/* checkmarks */

.whatsapp .out dd sub:after {
  content: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azdaema/AO3-Skin_Messaging/master/WhatsApp/images/Checkmark_read.png");
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.whatsapp .out dd sub.received:after {
  content: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azdaema/AO3-Skin_Messaging/master/WhatsApp/images/Checkmark_received.png");
}

.whatsapp .out dd sub.notreceived:after {
  content: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azdaema/AO3-Skin_Messaging/master/WhatsApp/images/Checkmark_no-received.png");
}


/*
 * Big emojis
 */

.whatsapp dd.emoji1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji1 sub,
.whatsapp dd.emoji2 sub,
.whatsapp dd.emoji3 sub {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji1 sub {
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji2 sub {
  font-size: 0.375em;
}

.whatsapp dd.emoji3 sub {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}


/*
 * Pictures
 */

.whatsapp .pic {
  padding: 3px;
}

.whatsapp .pic img {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* Timestamp white and in image corner */

.whatsapp .pic.solo sub {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 5px;
}


/*
 * Contact header
 */

.whatsapp .contact {
  position: relative;
  background: #075E54;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: left;
}


/* avatar circle */

.whatsapp .contact:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/64/67/80/240_F_64678017_zUpiZFjj04cnLri7oADnyMH0XBYyQghG.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Online status */

.whatsapp .contact.online:after {
  content: "Online";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*
 * Group chat
 */

.whatsapp.grouptext .in dt {
  display: table !important;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p1 dt {
  color: #e54c51;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p2 dt {
  color: #ee7d37;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p3 dt {
  color: #dfa64f;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p4 dt {
  color: #58b042;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p5 dt {
  color: #58bfe8;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p6 dt {
  color: #367cdc;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p7 dt {
  color: #6f4bf5;
}

.whatsapp.grouptext .in.p8 dt {
  color: #ec68a1;
}
```

```html
<dl class="whatsapp grouptext">
  <div class="out">
    <dt>Ciri</dt>
    <dd time="2:01 PM">Who's picking me up today?</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in p1">
    <dt>Yennefer</dt>
    <dd>its tuesday</dd>
    <dd>so jaskier</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in p2">
    <dt>Jasker</dt>
    <dd>no its geralts turn</dd>
    <dd>i swear its his turn</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in p3">
    <dt>Geralt</dt>
    <dd>no, Yen is right: it's your turn</dd>
    <dd>it's tuesday</dd>
    <dd>Tuesday is always your turn</dd>
  </div>
</dl>

<hr>

<dl class="whatsapp">
  <h1 class="contact online">Mabel</h1>
  <h4 class="day">Today</h4>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>How's babysitting for Soos and Melody going?<sub>11:49 AM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>So I made chicken nuggets for lunch<sub>1:07 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>And you remember how much we used to love chicken nuggets!!!!! but when I tried one now it was just kind of bland and gross<sub>1:07 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>How sad is that??!<sub>1:07 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>I feel like an adult and I hate it<sub>1:07 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>Does it help if I say texting me to lament about chicken nuggets is super un-adult?<sub>1:08 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>maybe a little<sub>1:08 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>I bet we could make good chicken nuggets at home if we tried<sub>1:08 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd class="emoji1"><sub>1:08 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>I mean it's just bite-sized breaded chicken, right? You still like chicken and bread<sub>1:09 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>loving this can-do spirit brobro<sub>1:09 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>Also it makes you sound like antoni on queer eye<sub>1:09 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>Making An Effort <sub>1:10 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>and making chicken nuggets<sub>1:10 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>:swoon:<sub>1:10 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>Oooooh can we make them dinasour shaped<sub>1:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>I think the reason they can make the store bought ones shaped is because they're not actually made out of chicken, they're made out of paste<sub>1:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>wait<sub>1:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>Shit did I just destroy our childhood?<sub>1:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>No<sub>1:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>Maybe a little<sub>1:12 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>We could take real chicken and grind it up??<sub>1:13 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>It works for hamburgers. Mix in onion and stuff<sub>1:13 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>I can't decide if onion would be good, or if it would be sacrilegious to the spirit of chicken nuggets<sub>1:13 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>If they have onion but are dinosaur shaped, would that be a fair trade?<sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>yes<sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd class="emoji2"><sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>ALL THE SHAPES!!<sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd class="emoji3"><sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>That seems ambitious<sub>1:14 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>Bread on the outside! Bread on the inside!<sub>1:15 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>If the bread was on the inside the chicken would dry out<sub>1:15 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>beef jerky is good<sub>1:15 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>Fair poin<sub>1:16 PM</sub>t</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>CHICKEN NUGGET CINNAMON ROLLS!!!<sub>1:16 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>bread on the inside AND the outside<sub>1:16 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>To what ends?<sub>1:16 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>Defying chicken-bread roles<sub>1:17 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>why does the bread always have to be on the outside, shielding the chicken from the drying heat of the oven?? Doesn't bread deserve to be protected sometimes too<sub>1:17 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>Can't argue with that<sub>1:17 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>Wait so were you actually serious about making chicken nuggets?? I'm at the store now, should I buy some chicken?<sub>3:47 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd>yes get chicken<sub>4:11 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="out">
    <dt>Dipper</dt>
    <dd>Mabel we've talked about this<sub>4:12 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>When I say "I'm at the store NOW" you can't reply half an hour later still asking for stuff<sub>4:12 PM</sub>
    </dd>
    <dd>but yeah I got chicken<sub>4:16 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div class="in">
    <dt>Mabel</dt>
    <dd class="emoji1"><sub>4:16 PM</sub>
    </dd>
  </div>

</dl>
```

View on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Azdaema/pen/zYGOxaZ)

In WhatsApp group chat, the name appears as the top line of the first text that person sends in a series.

What I want:

[image]

At first I just tried this, to make some space, and then translated the name into place.

```css
.whatsapp.grouptext .incoming dt+dd {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
```

But if someone just says "no" or something, then the text bubble is that narrow, and it's not wide enough for the name. Both names and texts can vary in length, and I'd really rather not hard-code either to a fixed pixel size or something.

What I really want is to merge the two into a single element, or to turn the contents of `<dt>` into a `:before` for `<dd>`. Is there any way to do that?

(And yes, I *could* just wrap those top two in a `<div>` or whatever. But is there any other way??)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not sure what you're asking here. Can you provide a working snippet (edit the question and use the snippet feature)? Also, a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish or even seeing would be helpful.

Comment: Added images and a link to the CSS I have now

Comment: There is a **LOT** of CSS here can you create a [MCVE] , note *minimal*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the `<div>` into `<ul>` and each text message into a `<li>`. Each `<li>` has:

- Default values assigned as [CSS variables](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-css-variables-custom-properties/) <sup>`[1]`</sup>

  ```
  --variableName: value
  ...
  property: var(--variableName);
  ```

---

- [Pseudo-element `::before` and `content: attr()` property and value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) were used for group name <sup>`[2]`</sup>, user name <sup>`[4]`</sup>, and timestamp <sup>`[5]`</sup>

  ```
  <tagName attributeName="attributeValue">Text content</tagName>
  ```

  ---

  ```
  selector::before { content: '#'attr(attributeName)': ';...
  /* Result as Rendered HTML
  #attributeValue: Text content
  */
  ```

---

- Various [`background` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) were used for an avatar image <sup>`[3]`</sup>.
- Custom styles were assigned to specific `#id` <sup>`[6]`</sup>.

#### Demo

**Note:** The initial iframe provided to display demo is not rendered to any realistic dimensions. To review the demo properly, click the `Full page` link located to the right.

```css
/* [1] Defaults */
:root {
  /* Default avatar */
  --img: url(https://i.ibb.co/Br95K5G/wa0000000.png);
  /* Default background colors */
  --grn: rgba(12, 128, 8, 0.6);
  --lav: rgba(8, 12, 128, 0.6);
}

:root,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font: 700 3vw/1.45 Arial;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px ridge #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h1::before {
  /* [2] Group name */
  content: attr(data-group);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.text {
  padding: 4rem 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1.25rem 1.25rem 1.25rem 3.75rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* [3] Avatar */
  list-style: none;
  background-image: var(--img);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0.5rem center;
  background-size: 2.5rem;
}

li::before {
  /* [4] User name */
  content: attr(data-user)': ';
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 -5px;
  padding: 4px 0 2px 10px
}

.outgoing li,
.incoming li::before {
  background-color: var(--grn)
}

.incoming li,
.outgoing li::before {
  background-color: var(--lav)
}

time {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 75%;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

time::before {
  /* [5] Timestamp */
  content: attr(datetime);
}

/* [6] Custom styles by user #id */
#wa2813224 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/Hdyh0V0/wa2813224.png);
  background-color: #000;
  color: gold
}

#wa1248791 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/d6bK0fZ/wa12248791.png)
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px ridge #000;
  background-color: #000;
}

#ui * {
  font: inherit
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

#message {
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-top: 5px inset #333;
  border-bottom: 5px inset #333;
  border-left: 5px inset #333;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  resize: vertical;
}

#send {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--lav);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  :root,
  body {
    font: 700 4vw/1.45 Arial;
  }
  
  header {
    height: max-content
  }
  
  h1 {    
    margin: -8px 0;
  }
  
  time {
    margin-left: 65%;
  }
  
  #send {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 1px 3.5%;
    font-size: 0.75rem;  
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
    word-break: break-word;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class='whatsapp group'>
  <header>
    <h1 data-group='Carpool'></h1>
  </header>
  <section class="text">
    <ul class="outgoing">
      <li id='wa1275966' data-user='Ciri'>Who's picking me up today?<time datetime='10:21 PM'></time></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <ul class="incoming">
      <li id='wa0000000' data-user='default'>Hello world!<time datetime='10:26 PM'></time></li>
      <li id='wa2813224' data-user='zer00ne'>Not me.<time datetime='10:31 PM'></time></li>
      <li id='wa1248791' data-user='Aza Azdaema'>It's Tuesday...it's your turn.<time datetime='10:35 PM'></time></li>
      <li id='wa2813224' data-user='zer00ne'>I don't have enough gas.<time datetime='10:45 PM'></time></li>
      <li id='wa2813224' data-user='zer00ne'>Plus I'm not scheduled for Tuesdays. In fact I don't even work Tuesdays.<time datetime='10:46 PM'></time></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <form id='ui'>
      <fieldset>
        <textarea id='message' rows='1' cols='50'></textarea>
        <button id='send' type='submit'>Send</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all going through a website that has a really strict CSS whitelist and doesn't allow `attr()`. But this looks solid, and under normal circumstances, this would be a great fix—thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,

1. You need the full name + text to come in one bubble.
   For that you can give background and styling to the .in and .out divs. Same goes for the pointing arrow.
2. You need to have some width, so the bubble has some width.
   For this remove the float left/right given to dd.

Rest you can fix using margin and padding.